# How to specify the rows cols of textarea in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Inside my Model I have this code:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "News content is required.")]

[DisplayName("News Content")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string FullContent { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "News summary is required.")]
[DisplayName("News Summary")]
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Summary { get; set; }
```

And inside the View is:

```
<tr>
<td id="td-caption">Full Content</td>  
<td id="td-content2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FullContent)  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FullContent)</td>  
</tr>  
<tr>
<td id="td-caption">Summary</td>
<td id="td-content2">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Summary)@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Summary)</td>
</tr>
```

And inside my CSS:

```
textarea#FullContent, #Summary
{
width: 95%;
padding-top: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
cols: 20;
rows: 20;
}
```

But no effect at all. What should I do?  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rows` and `cols` are not valid CSS rules. They are attributes on the `textarea` element. But since you are using en `EditorFor` helper you cannot set their values. You could use the `width` and `height` properties in your CSS to adjust the size of the textarea:

```
textarea#FullContent, #Summary {
    width: 90px;
    height: 200px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: @Darin the first word is rols but it must be rows. I didnt could edit it because of stack overflow rules about edit must be at least six character. Please correct it.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative that allows the number of rows to be specified using a textarea is:

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments, new { @rows=10, @cols=40 })
```

source: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/596208/Html-BeginFormplusrowsplusandpluscols